# Automatically Rebase and Squash Git History From a Commit ID to HEAD from Branch to Master

Tags: git, rebase, git-squash

Is it possible to use `git rebase` to remove all of the history from a specific commit to the HEAD revision?

With `git -i rebase`, you have to count all of the commits in the `git log` and manually get squash of all of them except one commit before pushing the changes.

Is there a one-liner to do the following:

1. `git rebase -i HEAD~4` for 4 commits
2. Within the text editor, squash everything and keep one pick (I think you have to pick at least one commit)
3. `git fetch origin` to update the references
4. `git rebase origin/master` to rebase the branch onto the master
5. `git checkout master` to switch to the master branch
6. `git merge branch_name` to merge the branch onto the master

Is it possible to do this with less steps or other flags?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `git rebase -i` you can run [`git rebase --soft <commit-id>`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset#git-reset---soft) to move `HEAD` to `<commit-id>` without changing the index or the working tree then [`git commit`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit) to create a new commit that contains all the changes since `<commit-id>`.

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you're after is [git commit --fixup](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit#git-commit---fixupltcommitgt).  [Thoughtbot's writeup on automating this](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/autosquashing-git-commits) might interest you.